# Display a PDF from Reporting Services

Tags: c#, pdf, reporting-services

I would like to display a PDF generated from Reporting Services from my WinForms app.

I tried the following:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://myReportServer?MyReport&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:Format=pdf");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(uri.ToString());
```

Which launches a browser, which then in turn prompts me to open or save this file.

Ideally I would like to display only the file, either in the browser or in a PDF viewer.  Problem is I have to open both the browser and then PDF viewer, which the users doesn't want.

Is there a simple way to do this using just the URL?

My other alternative is to just write some C# code which seems straight forward.  There are some examples here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bsherwin/archive/2007/04/29/112094.aspx

and here:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/reporting-services/PDFUsingSQLRepServices.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download PDF to disk and then use Process.Start to show it.

Take a look at this example:

```
        Uri uriDownload = new Uri("http://myReportServer?MyReport&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:Format=pdf");
        string strSavePath = @"C:\test\test123.pdf";

        System.Net.WebClient wcli = new System.Net.WebClient();
        wcli.DownloadFile(uriDownload, strSavePath);
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strSavePath);
```

**UPDATE:**

If that does not work by default, try to add this before wcli.DownloadFile():

```
        wcli.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain");
        wcli.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good however I tried that and got the following error 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'  I wasn't getting any errors with my original code. Is there something I need to do?

Comment: @HABAN, unfortunately I don't have access to all the user passwords.  Is there something I can do to ensure I use Integrated Authentication?

Comment: @HABAN, ok I got it:  webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

Comment: I am currently trying the same thing and am receiving 403 (Forbidden). Works locally, but not in production. URL works when pasted into browser. Any idea why? Have tried a few user agents and setting proxy credentials.