# Integrate SSRS with AngularJS?

Tags: .net, angularjs, reporting-services

I have a project, the frontend is using pure HTML5/AngularJS, webservice is using .NET, and report is SSRS.

I have a major problem of displaying SSRS reports on frontend. We tried to embed the report in an iFrame but it pops credentials always, so it is not practical.

I want to know if it is possible that the backend can retrieve the SSRS report, wrap it as HTML or other consumable format, exposes as a webservice. Frontend call the webservice and display on the screen.

Is there any sample code for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [Display a PDF from Reporting Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513984/display-a-pdf-from-reporting-services) except in your case you could download the format .HTML and embed it in your IFrame

So something like:

```
Uri uriDownload = new Uri("http://myReportServer?MyReport&rs%3aCommand=Render&rs:Format=html");
string strSavePath = @"C:\temp\report.html";

System.Net.WebClient wcli = new System.Net.WebClient();
wcli.DownloadFile(uriDownload, strSavePath);
```

Then set the IFrame's src to the downloaded file.