# How to display SSRS report (PDF) in browser and not as download

Tags: reporting-services

I have setup a report URL that will out put a PDF but it shows up as a download.  I would like it to auto display in the browser.

Is this possible?

Comment: remove the `&rs:Format=PDF` from the end of the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display a PDF from Reporting Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5513984/display-a-pdf-from-reporting-services)